# Cannot open JQuery UI dialog more than once on Drupal

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal, jquery-ui-dialog

I've checked my code and it works fine but for some reason I cannot open Dialog once it was closed. Any advice on why is that?

The code is here - http://jsfiddle.net/EA2Dg/1/

Comment: Is it any internal Drupal thing or something?

Comment: where do you have this javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use "click function to open the dialog, it should work

HTML

```
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
    <p>This is an animated dialog which is useful for displaying information. The     dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
</div>

<button id="opener">Open Dialog</button>
```

JQuery:

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $("#opener").click(function(){
        $("#dialog").dialog();
    });
});
</script>
```